# In C, change lower vowel in a string to upper and change upper ones to lower

Tags: c

Here is my attempt, after testing, it changes every lower letter in my string to upper and every upper letter to lower.

I think my fifth line of code somehow did not work, it changes every letter instead of just vowels. Please give me some advice on how to improve it?

(I'm forbidden to use string.h)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX_STR_LEN 1024

void change_vowel(char somestr[MAX_STR_LEN])
{
    for (int x = 0; somestr[x]!= '\0'; x+=1)
    {
        if ((somestr[x] == 'A' || somestr[x] == 'E' || somestr[x] == 'I' || somestr[x] == 'O' || somestr[x] == 'U'));
        {
            if (islower(somestr[x]))
            {
                somestr[x] = toupper(somestr[x]);
            }
            else
            {
                somestr[x] = tolower(somestr[x]);
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two little mistakes, both in this line

```
if ((somestr[x] == 'A' || somestr[x] == 'E' || somestr[x] == 'I' || somestr[x] == 'O' || somestr[x] == 'U'));
```

1. The line ends with a semicolon `;` which means, the code below will always get executed. To the compiler, this will (roughly, let's ignore the new block for now) look like that:

   ```
   if ((somestr[x] == 'A' || somestr[x] == 'E' || somestr[x] == 'I' || somestr[x] == 'O' || somestr[x] == 'U'))
   {
       // Nothing here
   }

   if (islower(somestr[x]))
   {
       somestr[x] = toupper(somestr[x]);
   }
   else
   {
       somestr[x] = tolower(somestr[x]);
   }
   ```
2. You wouldn't change lowercase vowels to uppercase, because you only check for uppercase vowels. I suggest adding a `toupper()` so it becomes `toupper(somestr[x]) == 'A'` or to have another `if` below which checks the lowercase vowels. The second approach would save the extra check if it is lower-/uppercase.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I never knew the meaning of ";" before. Now everything seems working.

Comment: If you compiled with `-Wall` [on `clang`], the `if` statement would be flagged with a warning (`-Wempty-body`). (i.e.) it flags anything of the form `if (whatever); do_something;` The compiler realizes you probably meant `if (whatever) do_something;` It's [only] a warning, because with pre-processing, it _might_ [rarely] be correct. This is default on for `clang`, but `gcc` needs an _explicit_ `-Wempty-body` option.